# ID Token from AdminInitiateAuth invalid for API Gateway call

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an API Gateway with Authorizer. The Authorizer is using Cognito to verify the user. So far, I've managed to get the token (ID Token) using Android, and successfully call the API with Authorizer. However, when I'm using Java, I'm using AdminInitiateAuth with ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH, and the token received is invalid for the Authorizer. Both access token and ID token is invalid when testing with Authorizer. Is the ID Token actually different and cannot be used in the same way as from Android?

I tried searching in the AWS documentation, and it doesn't seem to indicate that the different method will produce different type of token. Or maybe I've misunderstood the whole authentication process and difference between normal user and admin.

Comment: Please share sample codes/CLI commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by checking the authorizer. If you are using different client app in the same user pool, make sure in the Authorizer, Token Validation is set to none. Mine is set to the first client app when I first set it up, so it doesn't work when it tries to validate from another client app.